# Android Studio Error : Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I am new to Android Development. I am using Firebase in this project but I am getting this error during gradle:build

> Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.

This is my build.gradle file :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.health.healthbloom"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.21'
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.4.3'

}
```

I have tried adding this in Dependencies also :-

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

Comment: The plugin is configured in your root level build.gradle.  Be sure to follow all of the instructions in the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your build.gradle dependencies:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
```

Also, remove

```
apply plugin:'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

from your project/build.gradle and add it to your app/build.gradle.

You can also check here for more info https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#manually_add_firebase

Answer (score 0):

You can simply delete all implementations from firebase, than go to `Tools > Firebase` and connect everything you need without headaches

Comment: Tried and tested but still getting the same error. Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you please add your project-level gradle to a question? Maybe I know where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

just do a `clean build` and `rebuild` it too or else do `invalidate cache and restart`
it will restart your android studio freshly.

you can find it that in file>invalidate cache and restart would be there

Comment: Thank you ! I have tried it but it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to dependency didn't solve :

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Try to Add this :

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:+'
```

to the root build.gradle. Check `Go To Setting > Android SDK > SDK Tools > Google Play Service`